# How to differentiate file & directory in the output of du -sh

Tags: linux, disk-space-utilization, du

The output of `du -sh * | sort -h` lists all the files and directories in sorted order based on size. But the problem is; the output doesn't differentiate the directories from files.

For example:

```
15K file1backup
16K Desktop
```

Is there any option to du which makes it easier to differentiate the files and directories?

Comment: I'm afraid this is really a RTFM question. See answer below.

Comment: @Unbeliever Thank you, since i couldn't figure out exact options which will differentiate the directories from files in man page i thought of asking here. If you feel irritated by this question sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

The nearest I could get using the original command from OP was this:

```
 ls -p | xargs -I{} du {} -sh | sort -h
```

..which now seems to work.

Comment: You don't need `-I{}` if you use `xargs du -sh` (and let the variable args go at the end by default), but you need to add `-d'\n'` if any filenames contain whitespace (except newline), quotes or backslash.

Answer (score 0):

No, my reading of the manual says that du does not differentiate between files and directories.

---

You cold differentiate yourself with something like

```
find  . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | du -sh --files0-from -
```

for files and

```
 find  . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | du -sh --files0-from -
```

for directories. Adjust other parameters as required.

Answer (score 0):

Does [**`man du`**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/du) offer a switch to do so? - **No**.

Can you be clever about it? **Maybe**.

`du -s */ |sort -n` will restrict you to subdirectories, excluding the files in your $PWD and you can use `ls` to sort those files by size quite easily with `ls --group-directories-first -Ssh`.

Or use a different tool altogether: [`ncdu`](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/scr)

Answer (score 0):

You really should try the manual. Simply doing `du -h` will only do directories you actually have to *add* an argument to get it to do files as well (`-a`).  The reason your command does files is because of the `*`.

If you only want top level directories sorted, probably the simplest is:

```
du -h | grep -v '[^.]/' | sort -h
```